# Adding legend to a pie-chart in sencha

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts

I have this pie chart in sencha

```
{
                        xtype: 'polar',
                        height: 600,
                        id: 'genderPieChart',
                        padding: 5,
                        title: 'Chart showiing the number of Males and Females ',
                        colors: [
                            '#115fa6',
                            '#94ae0a'
                        ],
                        store: 'GenderStore',
                        series: [
                            {
                                type: 'pie',
                                xField: 'counter',
                                yField: 'types'
                            }
                        ],
                        interactions: [
                            {
                                type: 'rotate'
                            }
                        ],
                        legend: {
                            xtype: 'legend',
                            itemSelector: 'div',
                            itemTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate', 
                                '',
                                {
                                    definitions: [
                                        'Male, Female'
                                    ]
                                }
                            )
                        }
                    }
```

I need to add a legend to it using the fielfd from my model, the model being

```
Ext.define('Qvidi.model.MyModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
alias: 'model.MyModel',

requires: [
    'Ext.data.field.Integer'
],

fields: [
    {
        name: 'types'
    },
    {
        type: 'int',
        name: 'counter'
    }
]
});
```

as you can see I did add the legend in the first block of code, but I need it to be configured, and i don't know how, tried everything i could think of, so far unsuccessful

Comment: I think you need a `docked` descriptor inside `legend`, but I'm not really sure. Also, what have you tried by far?

Comment: I tried adding a function which I now deleted that would try get the data from the model but it didnt work, I also added the store im using to the legend then I just got a huge error in the browser. This is when i looked a the page on the browser with inspect tools enabled on chrome

Comment: This is the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'dom' of null

Comment: can you please try to share a fiddle? so we can try to solve better the problem?